# Display image in cli (with python on rpi) FBI, FIM, Pillow, Wand etc

Tags: python, pi-zero-w, fbi

I have managed to display an image on the screen attached to my pi using FBI with the command `sudo fbi -a -noverbose -T 2 /home/pi/image.jpeg`, however it seems to cause some issues where it crashes the Desktop/cli of the pi with the following error on a black screen:

```
map: vt02 => fbo
Oops: Interrupt
map: vt02 => fbo
map: vt02 => fbo
Oops: Interrupt
map: vt02 => fbo
map: vt02 => fbo
```

It seems to mainly happen if I run the command above multiple times without `sudo killall -2 fbi` in between, however sometimes it just happens anyway.

I have also tried to use pillow and Wand but pillow doesn't work at all and neither work in cli only mode:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='/home/pi/image.jpeg') as img:
    display(img)
```

Is there a way I can fix or tame fbi and is there a way I can programatically use this from Python reliably?  There's just one image I want to display and I don't need to manipulate it or anything so my requirements are quite straightforward.  Thanks!

Edit:
The purpose of displaying the image is as a splash/loading screen whilst my Kivy app builds, so whatever solution I go with needs to be non-blocking and ideally as straightforward as possible

Comment: You could use the pygame library to display an image https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=252805#p1544669

Comment: Thanks but it seems overly complex for what I require. I simply want to display a splash screen image for a few seconds whilst my Kivy app is building, so it also needs to be non-blocking

Comment: Add those details to your question.

Comment: It may help your research to think of the context as the [linux framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) (the "fb" in fbi) rather than the CLI, which it actually is not, ie., the framebuffer and CLI are available on the *console*, but they are not the same thing.